# Tricycle conversion kit for 24 inch yita home tricycle

Tags: beginner, tricycle, motor

What all do I need to buy? Couldn't afford expensive electric kit.what is a good petrol gas kit?

[image] 
<sub>From [https://www.amazon.com/YITAHOME-Tricycle-Shifting-Removable-Shopping/dp/B0BYZS7L47?th=1&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BYZS7L47)</sub>

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Unfortunately there recommendation questions aren't a good fit for the site, so are considered off-topic.  If you have a particular kit you have questions about using, we might be able to answer specific questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

Good petrol/gasoline kit?  There aren't any - they're all horribly noisy and inefficient.  Also, based on this rear-end photo your trike has a solid beam rear axle with no differential.  There's a band brake or a drum brake too which has to remain.

This means any rear wheel kit will need some kind of fabrication to fit.

[image]

If you want to motorise, I'd suggest a front wheel replacement electric motor like the old-school hilltopper or clones.  These replace your entire front wheel, and have a battery and a throttle.  The battery would replace your water bottle cage and use the mounts

Just be sure any candidate has a rim brake track to match your V brake on the front wheel.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure there aren't any rear wheel kits that fit this type of axle anyway. A mid motor would be an option, but in the absence of a differential i fully agree that a front motor would be the best choice here.